# Using IQueryable.GroupBy to count related database entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given a `DbSet<Client>` from an Entity Framework 6 `DbContext`, I need to count the number of related `Ticket`s of each type: `Open`, `Responded`, and `Resolved`.

The below code works, and results in only one query (according to `DbContext.Database.Log`), as desired. However, the fact that the call to `GroupBy` results in an `IGrouping<Client, ICollection<Ticket>>`, which is also an `IEnumerable<ICollection<Ticket>>`, requires me to call `FirstOrDefault()`, even though there is always only one `ICollection<Ticket>`.

I've never used `GroupBy` before, so I'm willing to bet I'm just misusing it.

```
public IEnumerable<DashboardItemViewModel> GetItems(IQueryable<Client> clients)
{
    return clients
        .Where(cli => cli.IsActive)
        .GroupBy(cli => cli, cli => cli.Tickets)
        .Select(grp => new DashboardItemViewModel
        {
            Id = grp.Key.Id,
            Name = grp.Key.Name,
            Open = grp.FirstOrDefault().Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Open && !t.IsArchived),
            Responded = grp.FirstOrDefault().Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Responded && !t.IsArchived),
            Resolved = grp.FirstOrDefault().Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Resolved && !t.IsArchived),
        });
}

public enum StatusType
{
    Open,
    Responded,
    Resolved,
};

public class DashboardItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Open { get; set; }
    public int Responded { get; set; }
    public int Resolved { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StatusType Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @tinstaafl I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: @tinstaafl Obviously my question is unclear. What can I explain? "How to retrieve a single result" and "counting related records with GroupBy" seem like very different things.

Comment: *The below code works* -- Really? Doesn't `GroupBy(cli => cli, cli => cli.Tickets)` thow an exception? That would mean that `clients` is not an `IQueryable` originating from a `DbSet` but actually is an `IEnumerable`. Both with EF6 and EF-core, grouping by a collection should throw an exception. BTW, please indicate which EF version this is.

Comment: @GertArnold Really. Wouldn't it only be grouping by a collection if a collection is the key? It's EF6, I'll edit the post when I get a chance.

Comment: Yes you're right, I missed the `cli => cli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the grouping at the `Client` level. No grouping at all, actually. Don't worry, [this is a common mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951571/861716) when people want grouping/aggregation in child collections. Per client, the `Tickets` can be counted:

```
return clients
    .Where(cli => cli.IsActive)
    .Select(cli => new DashboardItemViewModel
    {
        Id = cli.Id,
        Name = cli.Name,
        Open = cli.Tickets.Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Open && !t.IsArchived),
        Responded = cli.Tickets.Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Responded && !t.IsArchived),
        Resolved = cli.Tickets.Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Resolved && !t.IsArchived),
    });
```

Or in query syntax, so we can benefit from the `let` statement:

```
return from cli in clients
    where cli.IsActive
    let activeTickets = cli.Tickets.Where(t => !t.IsArchived)
    select new DashboardItemViewModel
    {
        Id = cli.Id,
        Name = cli.Name,
        Open = activeTickets.Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Open),
        Responded = activeTickets.Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Responded),
        Resolved = activeTickets.Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Resolved)
    };
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Do you have any idea if [SQL Server](https://hastebin.com/osupatapay.sql) will optimize those counts, i.e. loop once (like [this](https://hastebin.com/lohijapupi.cs) rather than once for each `StatusType` (like [this](https://hastebin.com/fozijijegi.cs))? If not, there's the possibility of doing the counting myself, rather than asking the database to... Also, is the benefit of `let` just clarity?

Comment: I can't see your links, but  `let` doesn't improve the generated SQL. It's for clarity and for preventing repetitive code. The generated SQL will contain three `COUNT` subqueries. In a similar query I see that each subquey is executed separately. If there's a performance issue you could try to improve that by fetching an anon. type with `StatusTypes = activeTickets.Select(t => tStatusType)` and do grouping/counting of `StatusTypes` in memory. Can't tell if that will be any better.

Comment: ... If there are many tickets per client the amount of data going over the wire may be significantly larger than a (maybe) slower counting query returning 3 numbers per client.

Comment: Sorry about that, not sure what's wrong with hastebin. The links were just examples to make sure what I was talking about was clear, but I think it's safe to say you understand. Thanks for your help, I'll go ahead and mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work the way you think it does.

> ```
> .GroupBy(cli => cli, cli => cli.Tickets)
> ```

This is not grouping anything because you are using the entire object as a key and since you are not providing any comparer for them each group will have exactly one item, itself.

> ```
> .Select(grp =>
> ```

Then from each one-itemed-group you select its single item with

> ```
> grp.FirstOrDefault().Count(t => t.Status == StatusType.Open
> ```

This is probably very inefficient because the grouping isn't grouping anything and works like a `SELECT * FROM Table`.

Instead you should rather be doing this. Select tickets from active clients, group them by their `Status`, calculate their `Count` and then create the view-model.

```
    var ticketGroups = tickets
        .Where(ticket => ticket.Client.IsActive)        
        .GroupBy(ticket => ticket.Status, tickets => tickets.Count())
        .ToList();

    return new DashboardItemViewModel
    {
        Id = grp.Key.Id,
        Name = grp.Key.Name,
        Open =  ticketGroups.SingleOrDefault(tg => tg.Key == StatusType.Open && !tg.IsArchived),
        Responded = ticketGroups.SingleOrDefault(tg => tg.Status == StatusType.Responded && !tg.IsArchived),
        Resolved = ticketGroups.SingleOrDefault(tg => tg.Status == StatusType.Resolved && !tg.IsArchived),
    });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use a `DbSet<Client>` at all and doesn't return an `IEnumerable<DashboardItemViewModel>`. Could you please update your answer or explain your reasoning?